# A ts script in my Angular app can't find the modules in node_modules

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I have an Angular app. 
I want to add a script in package.json.

The script is written in Typescript and his path is src/scripts/generate-blog-metadata.ts.

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const { resolve, join } = require('path');
const {fs} = require('fs');
const readdir = promisify(fs.readdir);
const stat = promisify(fs.stat);
```

My package.json :

```
  "scripts": {
    "generate-blog-metadata" : "node src/scripts/generate-blog-metadata.ts"
  },
```

When I run the script :

```
npm run generate-blog-metadata
```

I get an error :

```
/Users/pom/workspace/signalement-app/src/scripts/generate-blog-metadata.ts:6
const readdir = promisify(fs.readdir);
                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'readdir' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/john/workspace/signalement-app/src/scripts/generate-blog-metadata.js:6:30)
```

What I understand is the way I run my script make him unable to find the node_modules.

May be it's a webpack configuration problem, so this is the config file :

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    server: './server.ts',
  },
  target: 'node',
  resolve: {extensions: ['.ts', '.js']},
  externals: [/(node_modules|main\..*\.js)/,],
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader'}
    ]
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
      /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
      /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      {}
    )
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the extension generate-blog-metadata.js to generate-blog-metadata.ts

Comment: Thanks but there's an error with .ts and with .js. I corrected my question